# Express y in terms of x for equation $y = 2 x \sin (x) \cos (y)$

Tags: implicit-function

The below equation gives beautiful graph in desmos. I was trying to find a way to draw this graph using Javascript but for that I first need to express y in terms of x but I am not able to figure out a way, any pointers would be great.

$$y=2x(\sin x)(\cos y)$$

[image]

Comment: What leads you to believe this can be done in a clean fashion?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes it's difficult, as I have been trying to figure it out for quite a few hours now. I believe there should be a solution because I can see the graph plotted in desmos as well as in wolfram alpha

Comment: Those use "implicit plotting" techniques... one example of which would be looking at $f(x,y) = 2x\sin(x)\cos(y)-y$ using a grid of points, categorizing those points according to which had $f(x,y)$ positive, which had $f(x,y)$ negative and coloring the boundary between those respective regions (*as well as any points where $f(x,y)$ was identically zero*) to draw the graph you see.  They did not draw the graphs by solving for $y$.  With higher resolution (*more points in the grid*) you get more accurate looking graphs.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks! I think this is what I was looking for, the word "implicit plotting".  I have my answer.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5By+%3D%3D+2+x+Sin%5Bx%5D+Cos%5By%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-100%2C+100%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-100%2C+100%7D%5D

Comment: I prefer this one  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5By+%3D%3D+2+x+Sin%5Bx%5D+Cos%5By%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-10%2C+10%7D%5D

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I prefer it with range between -20, 20